# Matlab Function block to define Steady Space model (controller)

Tags: matlab

**Hello every one**

I have Steady-Space model(Controller) as below:

```
A =[ *M* ]; B =[0 0 2 0 0 0 0];;
C =[0;2;0]; D =[0 2 0 0 0 0 0 ; 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 ;  0 0 0 *M* 0 2 0]
```

`Controller =ss(A,B,C,D)`

This controller have 7 inputs and 3 outputs.

**I don't want to use simulink steady-space block to define this controller in it.**

As [How to change variables in time in Simulink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737926/how-to-change-variables-in-time-in-simulink)

I have variable M in my controller that can be changed with time and I want to use

variable signal to this scenario like top linked link.

How can I use user defined blocks to write this variable steady-space controller ?

Which **User defined blocks** can be use for programming and how?

**Need help**

Thanks

Comment: Every time I read "emergency" or "urgent" in a question I feel like voting down. What do you think StackOverflow is?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [Matrix Concatenate](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/vectorconcatenate.html) block to create your `D` matrix from your M signal , muxed with other constants (`0` and `2`) to create a vector, which you can then contatenate with 2 other constant vectors to create the matrix. Matrices `A`, `B`, and `C` are constant, so you can then just construct your state-space system from scratch using these 4 matrices, using simple Add, Multiply and Subtract blocks.

Another alternative is to use a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block, taking `M` as an input, but I don't know if state-space objects are allowed as a data type for the function output. I guess you'd need to compute the state-space output at each time step based on the state-space input. Not sure how you do that with a MATLAB Function block.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Could you please give a simple example that how can use Matrix Concatenate to create steady space system? Thank you

Comment: I don't have access to Simulink anymore unfortunately, but it's pretty easy. There are some examples in the block documentation.